# How to display value of array to comma separated values

Tags: typescript, angular7

`31: (2) ["https://localhost:44375/api/Image/2388", "https://localhost:44375/api/Image/2388"]`

I am getting value like this but I want to display it like,

`https://localhost:44375/api/Image/2388, https://localhost:44375/api/Image/2388`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Use `array.join(',')`

Comment: can u explain in brief

Comment: The join() method creates and returns a new string by concatenating all of the elements in an array (or an array-like object), separated by commas or a specified separator string.

Comment: please give an example

Comment: Why the question is tagged with `angular7`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

> The join() method creates and returns a new string by concatenating all of the elements in an array (or an array-like object), separated by commas or a specified separator string.

```js
const data = ["https://localhost:44375/api/Image/2388", "https://localhost:44375/api/Image/2388"],
result = data.join(', ');
console.log(result);
```